# how to change monaco-editor's display language like 'en-us','zh-cn' but not Programming Language like 'javascript','html'

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor

I've searched for a lot of documents, they all give ways to change Programming Language, but all I need is i18n.
`setModelLanguage(editor.getModel(), "language")`DOES NOT FIT THIS NEED.

Comment: There's nothing like a display language. Text internally is held as UTF-16 and printed whatever code point a character represents. Give it a chinese string and it will show chinese output. If that's not what you need enhance your question and describe in detail what you are after.